# How to access the images below in Constraint layout param in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-layoutparams

I use constraintlayout for container. I have to add images from camera and gallery in to container, so I have to use layout param. When I add imageview and set it to container, I have not access to under imageview. I have to do events move, rotate, zoom. I have to access imageview with touch listener.
please help me. thanks.

```
layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) ivCarpet.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = Math.round(ViewUtil.dpToPx(workSpaceWidth));
        layoutParams.height = Math.round(ViewUtil.dpToPx(workSpaceHeight));
        carpetContent.removeView(ocv);
        ivCarpet.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


 imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        imageView.setMaxWidth((int) sizeImage[0] / 4);
        imageView.setMaxHeight((int) sizeImage[1] / 4);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        carpetContent.addView(imageView);
```

Comment: what is not working here?

Comment: I don't know. but for touch event just access to up image view.

Comment: your question is unclear can you rephrase it so it can be easier to understand what you want or what is the issue.

Comment: I have base layout . and I want to add it some images from gallery, when images add to my layout just I access to upper image view. and I cant touch under images. I have to select other images that added in layout for events. but just move or rotate upper image. thank you.